# How can i pull new update and ignore existing changes?

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I am getting this error while running **git** command **git pull origin master** into **my server repository**.

```
please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge. aborting in 
 run of pull command
```

i am  facing this many time when run this. For solve this problem i tried **git reset --hard**. but there any other solution for this.

Actually problem is that i made some changes before pull and now master has some change in same file in which i am working. so i do want want to push current change and accept new changes that will come from Master Branch or Other Branch.

Comment: and? Do you disagree with the message? i.e., do you **not** have local changes that you should commit or stash or discard? Because if you do, the program is completely correct, and there is no problem here.

Comment: If you don't want to commit the changes you've added then you obviously would want to reset to a particular commit, otherwise you can first commit the changes then do git pull.

Comment: yes , i have comited my all local changes and then i pushed into master ... after that i pull back into my server repository...

Comment: next time do "git status" this will give you interesting information. 
reading some kind of tutorial on git would be helpful, think about creating branches  and rebasing branches etc...

Answer (score 1):

My experience is, when error or warring happen, follow Git client instruction.

> commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

therefore,

(1) `git stash`

(2) Merge

(3) `git stash pop`

Answer (score 0):

Yes git `git stash` is an option but sometime we have to keep current changes then we can do one thing we can make new Temporary Branch from current branch and then stash old branch. so by this way we can keep current code copy into temporary branch and accept new commit from new branch.

For this we have to create new branch.

```
    git checkout -b  <temporary_branch_name> 

    git merge <current_branch> // optional. because git checkout automatally  do it.

    git checkout <old branch name >  // come back on disputed branch

    git   stash  // remove current changes.

    git pull origin <branch_name> // for accept new changes.
```